# PHP Session timeout : session.gc_maxlifetime & session.cookie_lifetime

Tags: php

I have made changes in php.ini
session.gc_maxlifetime=10000

By default session.cookie_lifetime is set to 0

What I read is that if session.cookie_lifetime   is set to 0 , the session id is active till the browser is open.
My query is will session id expire after 10000 seconds or it will never expire till the browser is open since session.cookie_lifetime is set to 0